# How do I change the primary key in ObjectBox?

Tags: objectbox, objectbox-android

The primary key existed before and now it needs to be made new.

This is how I modified it, but duplicate data will appear.

Before:

```
@Entity
class A {
    @Id(assignable = true)
    long id;
}
```

Now:

```
@Entity
class A {
    @Id
    long boxId;
    long id;
}
```

Comment: current solution:
`@Uid(5958743963287218505L)
    @Unique(onConflict = ConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    long id;
`

But this modification will change all the existing ids to 0, so I also add a judgment on the data: if the id and boxId are both 0, then download the data again.